# common dependency install overwrite failure

Tags: maven, jenkins

I Have 2 jenkins pipelines

- Prj1
- Prj2

Here is how Maven Project is setup:

- Prj

  - Prj1
  - Prj2
  - Prj-commons

Both Prj1 and Prj2 depends on Prj-commons.

When Jenkins triggers a build (`mvn install`), usually Prj1 builds faster than than Prj2, Prj1 builds Prj-commons and installs into the repository. When Prj2 tries to install Prj-commons its already there and it fails since our internal repo is restricted (cannot overwrite an artifact)

Is there a way to skip/ignore install if the artifact already exists ? Any recommendations on where to handle this check Maven or Jenkins (I'm leaning towards handling this in maven, but still wondering how) ?

Comment: Why not running from root `Prj` via Maven and Maven handles the order?

Comment: Prj1 and Prj2 are 2 different ears meant to be deployed in two different servers

Comment: Building and deployment is something different. Build in one go and afterward deploy them onto servers...